# KnockoutJS Mapping - just fill in what I need from the server

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

One intuitive way I though I'd be able to use KO mappings plugin would be to create a naked viewModel with only whatever computed observables I needed, then update the vm with `fromJS` whenever server results came in.  I assumed missing properties would be added, and existing ones would be updated.

I thought I could just bind this naked ViewModel to my dom on document.ready, with any missing properties showing up blank.  Then, when an ajax callback fires, and the mapping library adds the new properties, the dom would update.

The results I saw seem to indicate that this isn't possible though, and I wanted to make sure I'm not missing anything.

The code is below, but the three main problems I found were:

- If the dom is bound to a property that's missing from the ViewMoel, that's an error.  This isn't surprising, especially given the lucid explanation below from @madcapnmckay.
- If a computed observable references a view model property that's absent from the ViewModel, that's an error.  I assume this is the case since all computedObservables are executed immediately so that KO can track which observable properties the computedObservable is dependent upon.
- Most devastating, it looks like an existing ViewModel can only be updated with `fromJS` if that ViewModel was **originally** created with `fromJS`.  Peeking in the code it looks like `fromJS` looks in the second parameter—if one is passed—to check for a mappings property.

I don't need any help working around this.  I've already come up with a simple way to deal with all this; I just want to make sure there's not something simple I'm missing on any of the above three bullets that would make things more easy.

---

VM:

```
    var vm = new (function () {
        this.prettyName = ko.computed(function () {
                return this.title() + " " + this.name();
        }, this);
    })();
```

"AJAX" result:

```
    var serverObj = {
        title: 'Mr.',
        name: 'Adam Rackis',
        degreeValue: 2,
        degreeTypes: [{ val: 1, txt: 'Bachelors' }, { val: 2, txt: 'Masters' }, { val: 3, txt: 'PhD'}]
    };
```

HTML

```
<div id="educationPane">
    Name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: prettyName" />
    Degree: <select data-bind="{foreach: degreeTypes, value: degreeValue}">
                <option data-bind="{text: text, value: val}"></option>
            </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have hit all of these same issues when working with KO. Point 1 and 2 in my opinion is simply a consequence of how KO works.

- When the dom is bound to a property that doesn't exist the binding
  needs to subscribe to the observable or display the property value in order to work. If you subsequently add that property to the viewModel how could the binding know that this had happened? (A more complex solution would be to allow viewModel objects themselves to be observable but that's another story)
- When a computed observable is created it's containing function is evaluated immediately so that subscriptions to observables can be recorded and the computed can reevaluate when needed. If no observables exist (immediate error, can be fixed with a test) or none are hit within the computed's evaluation it will not be evaluated again.
  -

Point 3 I concede is a pain. I don't know the reasons it was done this way. Maybe there were some good reasons. At the very least an 'update' method that simply updates properties and doesn't remove from collections would be useful.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you kindly for the reply.  Yeah, points one and two are not surprising (I even mentioned the same reasoning as you for point 2 in my question), but point 3 seems the most troubling.  I can't imagine why they would have done it that way.

Comment: @AdamRackis - I have been considering writing a base ViewModel class to implement the map/unmap/update functionality, I may take a look at that this weekend.